# How to generate a list of missing #include files

Tags: c++, makefile

**Background:** I am working on a large c++ project with multiple executable and library outputs with a set of working make files (i.e. assuming you had the entire code base, you could type make and it would build all libraries and executables).

My problem is that I must partially compile the project, and simply link in libraries that have been already compiled for other parts of the project. I have been supplied with the lib files for the other part of the project, but not all of the header files necessary to use the libraries.

**Question:** How do I go about generating a list of files that I will need to request in order to successfully finish compilation and then linking of parts of the project that have dependencies on the pre-compiled portion of the project? Just by running the make file, I get an error for the *first* missing dependency, but how can I generate a list of *all*?

**Things I have tried / Example:** Fire off the make script to compile and link `moduleA`. The make churns for awhile, and then issues an error that it can't find `moduleBCommon.h`, which was included from `moduleAxyz.h`. It can't find it because it does not exist on disk... I have not been provided the file, and must request it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have `moduleBCommon.h`, then you can't know what other headers it `#include`s, so I don't think it's possible to create the whole list before obtaining any of the missing headers.

Why can't you ask for all the header files associated with the libraries? Whoever is in charge of the libraries has already goofed by not providing them, and if nobody knows which header files go with the libraries then clearly someone has bungled the source control, so management should tolerate iterative requests from you.

(Unless your managers are technically incompetent, computer-illiterate, logically challenged MBA types, which is quite possible.)

Comment: Completely agree with this; it's not a build issue, it's a code management issue. They should provide you with the headers up front. It's a waste of everyone's time not to.

Comment: @Beta This isn't a matter of illiteracy, it's more a legal matter to shared rights (between companies) to a code baseline. It's complicated. Iterative approach, here we come...

Comment: @Josh: "The arguments of lawyers and engineers pass through one another like angry ghosts."

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the gcc compiler, this command will give you the missing header files:

```
gcc -M -MG filename.cpp
```

This lists all dependencies:

```
gcc -M filename.cpp
```

This lists dependencies that does not belong to the system headers:

```
gcc -MM filename.cpp
```

Comment: This will not detect a missing header file that is referred to only by other missing header files.

Comment: This also works with Clang! (This shouldn't come as a surprise, but I thought it'd be good to note.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the missing files, what you are immediately concerned with is more undefined types, classes or functions. Having a list of files that you miss will only be a first step, because they might forward-declare more classes for which you then again would have no definition if you need them.

The only free tool I have used to detect such dependencies was [cppcheck](http://code.google.com/p/checkheaders/). Development seems to have slowed down a lot and it produces some typical false positives, but other than that it does its job.